# Split large word table on next page

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a table which has a lot of columns as well as rows. Currently the table is split over multiple pages (which is fine). But since there are also too many columns they do not fit on one page.

Is it possible to split the table not only for rows, but also for columns?

**Example:**

If I have 20 columns Word will show the first **X** rows and 10 columns on the first page and then the last 10 columns for the same **X** rows on the second page and so on...

**Background:**

We currently use OpenXML in a C# application to generate some documents. The idea is to provide the customer with the best formatting and the user can then adapt the layout themselfs.

Currently the table is configured to be able to span over multiple pages (row wise) which works quite well. If one row gets deleted, the other ones will move up automatically, even across pages.

But we can not fit all columns on a page.

So one possible solution would be to cut the table at a certain column and just create a second one. But there is one major drawback: In case the customer decides to remove some columns it will be quite cumbersome for him to rearrange the other columns (glue the split tables together because there maybe is enough space now).

Comment: Word is not the same as Excel :-) No, Word does not have this functionality built-in. Using code, it would be possible to do something, I think. Are you looking for a code solution? It's not obvious from your Question... If yes, which programming language?

Comment: @CindyMeister see my updated question :-)

Comment: Why not to ceate another table for 10 columns and another table for another 10 columns?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal see my question, last paragraph

Comment: But there is no other way very probably, Excel would be more appropriate for this.

Comment: I agree with @VojtěchDohnal - Word can't do this automatically. Usually, the user could select a column (or columns), use the CUT command, select the "end-of-row-column" at the right of a table then PASTE to shift columns - that's not so terribly cumbersome?